# Displaying multiple items in SfRotator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I'm trying to display a form in `Syncfusion SfRotator` control. I have tried to use a `StackLayout` inside the rotator, and it won't work. The rotator will be loaded, but it doesn't show anything.

```
var item = new SfRotatorItem();
item.ItemContent = new StackLayout
{
    Children =
    {
        new Label {Text = "f", HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = Color.White, },
        Entry,
        Btn,
        noteLbl,
    }
};
rotator.DataSource.Add(item);
```

`ItemContent` accepts a `view`, I'll be grateful if you could help me with this or suggest another approach to show multiple controls in each page to create a progressive form.

Comment: were you ale to solve this issue?

Comment: No, I just used the default rotator that Xamarin offers.

Comment: Thanks, it's working for me. Seems like there is a bug, if you use any container like stacklayout or grid, the items do not show up. Try creating a simple one without any Stacklayout or grid in item template & it works fine.

Comment: The SfRotator has currently a bug, i reported it already to Syncfusion. A fix will be included in the Vol 2 release by the end of april 2017.